# Better solution than using too many switch cases

Tags: c#, selenium

I have this `switch case` to identify value from Excel and check to which function to call based on value pass in `DemoName` but I need a better solution than this:

```cs
public void SelectDemoAccount(string dataKeyname, string sheetName)
{
    var Demo = new Demoing(DriverHelper.GetDriver);
    var ud = ExcelDataHelper.GetTestData(dataKeyname, sheetName);
    String DemoName = ud.DemoName;
    switch (DemoName)
    {
        case "Abc":
            Demo.ClickAbc();
            break;
        case "Def":
            Demo.ClickDef();
            break;
        case "Ghi":
            Demo.ClickGhi();
            break;
        case "Dsa":
            Demo.ClickDsa();
            break;
        case "Qwe":
            Demo.ClickQwe();
            break;
        case "Zxc":
            Demo.ClickZxc();
            break;
        case "Hjk":
            Demo.ClickHjk();
            break;
        case "Fgh":
            Demo.ClickFgh();
            break;
        case "Cxz":
            Demo.ClickCxz();
            break;
        case "Nmq":
            Demo.ClickNmq();
            break;
        case "Atb":
            Demo.ClickAtb();
            break;
        case "Smt":
            Demo.ClickSmt();
            break;
        case "Mdt":
            Demo.ClickMdt();
            break;
        case "Ldt":
            Demo.ClickLdt();
            break;
        case "Cdt":
            Demo.ClickCdt();
            break;
        case "Hdt":
            Demo.ClickHdt();
            break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can build a `Dictionary<string, Action>` and set the key with your string and the action with the method to call. After that just index the array with the key and call the Action with Invoke

Comment: what is that element how are you finding it ?

Comment: @Steve if possible can you give a small example using my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `Dictionary` in which the `Key` is your string used in the current switch code and the `Value` is the method to execute from the *demo* variable.

```
var Demo = new Demoing(DriverHelper.GetDriver);
Dictionary<string, Action> demoMethods = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
demoMethods.Add("Abc", Demo.ClickAbc);
... add the other keyvalue pairs here
```

Now when you need to call the method just use

```
var ud = ExcelDataHelper.GetTestData(dataKeyname, sheetName);
String DemoName = ud.DemoName;
demoMethods[DemoName].Invoke();
```

This assumes that you have always the same instance of Demo to use, otherwise, if the code called is not static but requires to be executed on an instance of a `Demoing` class you need to have a set of static methods in your Demoing class. Each static method receives an instance of Demoing class to work with the underlying method.

```
public class Demoing
{
     public static void ClickAbc(Demoing current)
     {
        current.DoSomething();
        .... whatever ....
     }
}
```

So now you can prepare your dictionary using a different Action value,

```
Dictionary<string, Action<Demo>> demoMethods = new Dictionary<string, Action<Demo>>();
demoMethods.Add("Abc", Demoing.ClickAbc);
```

And when you need to call the method with a specific instance you write

```
var Demo = new Demoing(DriverHelper.GetDriver);
var ud = ExcelDataHelper.GetTestData(dataKeyname, sheetName);
String DemoName = ud.DemoName;
demoMethods[DemoName].Invoke(Demo);
```

Finally there is another way to employ the dictionary without using static methods and keep everything encapsulated inside the Demoing class. This idea comes from an answer now deleted by [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter).
Here the dictionary is internal to the Demoing class and a public method is given to access the dictionary actions as with:

```
public class Demoing
{
    private Dictionary<string, Action> nameActions;
      
    private Demoing()
    {
        InitNameActions();
    }

    private void InitNameActions()
    {
        nameActions = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            {"Abc", ClickAbc},
            // ...
        }
    }

    public Action GetAction(string name){
        return nameActions.TryGetValue(name, out Action action) ? action : null;
    }
}
```

and the call is the following

```
var demo = new Demoing(DriverHelper.GetDriver);
String demoName = ud.DemoName;
Action action = demo.GetAction(demoName);
action?.Invoke();
```

This way is better from an encapsulation stand point. But keep in mind that now each object of type Demoing has its Dictionary and, if you have a lot of Demoing objects around this could be not optimal for a memory footprint.

Comment: I would add the dictionary into the `Demoing` class and provide a method `GetAction(string name)` there. Then they dont need to be static and it's easy to use.

Comment: You can also [initialize a dictionary with a collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer). See aslo [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Comment: Hello @TimSchmelter I have finally found the time to update the answer with your observation. I shamelessly copied your answer. Please let me know if you want something changed.

Comment: No, it's fine. I just wonder why OP doen't use an enum instead of strings

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using reflection, it's slower but it works, and it requires less lines of code:

```
 var Demo = new Demoing(DriverHelper.GetDriver);
 var ud = ExcelDataHelper.GetTestData(dataKeyname, sheetName);
 var mi = typeof(Demoing).GetMethod("Click" + ud.DemoName);
 mi.Invoke(Demo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is create a map of key, value pair. Find DemoName  in all keys. If DemoName is key then execute value function.